# Crossing number algorithm in android

Tags: android, algorithm

I am building an asteroids-like game for Android. I am reading "android game programming by example". I am implementing the crossing number algorithm. The app is finished and it works, but I don't understand this part of the code:

```
if (((cp2.currentPoint.y > cp1.currentPoint.y) !=
    (cp2.currentPoint2.y > cp1.currentPoint.y)) &&
    (cp1.currentPoint.x < (cp2.currentPoint2.x - cp2.currentPoint2.x) *
    (cp1.currentPoint.y - cp2.currentPoint.y) / (cp2.currentPoint2.y - cp2.currentPoint.y) + cp2.currentPoint.x))
```

Where `cp1.currentPoint` is the first object's first vertex (so it is a point), `cp2.currentPoint` is the second object's first vertex and `cp2.currentPoint2` is the second point.  These two points form our line.

This part I don't understand:

```
(cp2.currentPoint2.x - cp2.currentPoint2.x)
```

The result of this is always 0, so why have I to do that?

Answer (score 0):

As you stated it being always zero, you don't need it. Maybe some other values were meant to be there but it was forgotten. So just take it out to clear your code.

Comment: Or perhaps it was transcribed incorrectly from the book?

Comment: The solution works most of the times  `(cp2.currentPoint.x - cp2.currentPoint2.x)`

Answer (score 0):

I read this book.At page 331 the author (John Horton) wrote,- "Well, at this point, we can fall back on a clever algorithm devised and refined by mathematicians far more than myself ". In my opinion, math related code at that book is very poor and John is not lying about himself(. You code can be rewriten:

```
if (((cp2.currentPoint.y > cp1.currentPoint.y) !=
   (cp2.currentPoint2.y > cp1.currentPoint.y)) 
   &&
   ((cp1.currentPoint.x < cp2.currentPoint.x)||
    (cp1.currentPoint.x < cp2.currentPoint.x)))
```

The firs two lines of the 'if' statement is to check
weather y position of a point is within height of a line formed
by two points. Other two lines makes sure that source of imaginary
ray is located always to the left of a line that being tested.

Besides that, John Horton is lying about great book "Beginning Android Games"
                     by Mario Zechner, telling that it would take around 600 pages of that book
                     to build a simple retro Snake game - outright lie! I recommend you to read book writen by Mario Zechner.